# VlookUP as a solution or Multiple 'IF , 'And' & 'Or' statements for an Excel query (non VBA)

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

Have been racking my brains with this problem, I usually through these sites get my solution but this one has me beat!!! So if anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Oh Hopefully you guys can make sense of my ramblings and problem :-)
The problem lies around the two different Inspection types and the two different times (dates) required to complete them. Inspection Type 1 has 3 days to be completed and Inspection Type 2 has one day . What I am looking for is a formula that when Columns A2000:E2000(could be more, could be less depends on the amount of inspections) are copied and pasted into the sheet Column F states(dynamically) If the Inspection Type is 'On Target' or 'Not on Target'

```
    A                 B           C            E                       F
1 Inspection Type   Date issued Date Due    Date Actually Completed   On Target
2 Inspection Type 1 19/05/2015  22/05/2015  20/05/2015                On Target
3 Inspection Type 1 18/05/2015  21/05/2015  24/05/2015                Off Target
4 Inspection Type 2 10/05/2015  11/05/2015  11/05/2015                On Target
5 Inspection Type 1 15/05/2015  16/05/2015  15/05/2015                On Target
6 Inspection Type 2 01/05/2015  02/05/2015  05/05/2015                Off Target
7 Inspection Type 1 05/05/2015  08/05/2015  09/05/2015                Off Target
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
=IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="1",IF(E2<=D2,"On Target 1","Off Target 1"),IF(RIGHT(B2,1)="2",IF(E2<=D2,"On Target 2","Off Target 2"),"Error"))

You will see I labelled the different targets, which you can alter if you wish - but helped me sort the errors. Does the inspection type always have the two names with no trailing spaces etc? Otherwise it will error. Also the inspection type is assumed to be in column B, if you will need to change the "right" statement.

Comment: Thanks Mike, will have  a play and see what happens :-)

Comment: Assuming the edited info above is correct, then code should now be changed as follows: replace RIGHT(B2,1) with TRIM(RIGHT(A2,1)) and E2<=C2. The addition of the TRIM function removes leading and trailing spaces to reduce errors. One thought is to just put "Ok 1" and "Ok 2" so the Off target labels show up more clearly.